# mvc3 how to return a list from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, list, controller

I have a list that I have on my view but this list is reused on multiple views and the list share the same information across all the views

```
// MyView.cshtml
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.type, new SelectList(new List<Object>{ 
                new { Text = "Automotive", Value = "Automotive"},
 new { Text ="Business", Value= "Business"}}}, "Value", "Text"))
```

That is the dropdownlist in view the issue is that the list sometimes changes thus I have decided to create the list in the controller that way if I need to change something I can do it in 1 place and it changes everything anyhow I was wondering how can I from the controller using a different actionResult make the list show in **MyView.cshtml**

```
 public ActionResult articleList()
    {
        var mylist = new List<articledrop>
       {
           new articledrop{ Text = "Automotive", Value = "Automotive"},
           new articledrop{ Text ="Business", Value= "Business"}

       };
        return View(mylist);
    }
```

as you can see i have created the list in the View **articleList.cshtml** now how can I make that list be shown on **MyView.cshtml** using a dropdownList .. any suggestions would be great

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a static class that contains the list, something like this:

```
public static class UtilLists
{
     public static List<articledrop> mylist = new List<articledrop>
     {
         new articledrop{ Text = "Automotive", Value = "Automotive"},
         new articledrop{ Text ="Business", Value= "Business"}
     };
}
```

And in the **View** you just call it this way:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.type, 
                      MvcApplication1.UtilLists.mylist.Select(option => new SelectListItem {
                                 Text = option.Text, 
                                 Value = option.Value}), 
                     "Choose..")
```

Let me know ;)